# multiple custom app in django

Tags: python, django

I want to have two custom made app dealing with **two different tasks**.
i have a page(template) where the data from the both app come together.
how to deploy url for that, in the common urls.py so that the two app work together. **how to integrate the views from both app to return data to same template simultaneously. is that possible?**

I found these situations in django books, but they have one custom made app and other one is built-in app. the apps are integrated in special way.

can u help to solve my problem with 2 custom app.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be a bit more specific. There's nothing magical about an app in Django - it's just a collection of models and views. If you need access to some of the models from one app in another app, just import them and use them as normal.